# Does Pacific Central Station (Vancouver) have a Global Entry/NEXUS machine?

Tags: borders, vancouver, global-entry, nexus

Is there a GE/NEXUS machine at the Pacific Central Station in Vancouver? I am traveling from Vancouver to Seattle.

Comment: Hey could you add a more detailed description how such a machine might look like? I'm maybe going to Pacific Central Station today and then I could have a look.

Comment: http://www.yvr.ca/Libraries/Annual_Reporting_-_Background_Images_Icons/passport_reader04.sflb.ashx http://www.rewardexpert.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Global-Entry1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had someone coming from Seattle to Vancouver to check out the station carefully and there is no sight of GE or NEXUS machines.

Answer (score -2):

When travelling by train between Vancouver and Seattle, a custom agent will board at the border and check each passenger's document. So you don't go through security/custom before boarding.

Comment: There's some sort of checkpoint now that mandates you to arrive earlier. I know the customs board the train but now there's a check at the train station.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: @JoErNanO It's an answer, but it's 100% wrong. US customs and immigration is juxtaposed here and control takes place at Pacific Central Station in Vancouver.