# Does Global Entry help when entering the US by bus or train?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, global-entry

I am a US citizen and recently signed up for Global Entry.  One of the benefits is a special card that one can use in NEXUS or SENTRI lanes when entering the US by foot or car, which could result in faster service.

My understanding is that I can also use this card to enter the US by bus or train, but in this case, does it have any advantage over using a passport or passport card?

For concreteness, this would likely be on either Megabus or Amtrak, entering the US from Canada at Niagara Falls.  I don't know what the immigration procedure is like on those services.

Comment: I only know the process on the west coast w/ NEXUS and I can tell you it doesn't help on [train](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34198/does-pacific-central-station-vancouver-have-a-global-entry-nexus-machine?s=1|1.1670) or bus.

Comment: Someone who's taken the Toronto-New York train fairly recently would need to answer that part. When I last took it a few years ago the immigration check in the Niagara Falls, NY station was done by CBP officers walking the train; a trusted traveler card offered no advantage. I understand that now they make everyone get off with their luggage and pass through customs in the station, but I've not done this and don't know what facilities they have there. FWIW the roadway that shares the railway bridge is NEXUS only and is the very best way to cross that border by car with a card.

Comment: When I did it yesterday, the officers did walk the train and you didn't have to get off, unless you needed an I-94 or some other additional processing.  Much nicer than standing in line.

Comment: You won't have any time advantage as the train doesn't continue until all passengers have been cleared. However, it is certainly an acceptable travel document to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The train stops at the Niagara Falls NY train station, and everyone is inspected there. Your NEXUS card works as a passport card so you don't need to carry your passport, but it won't save any time.